# Sentencias preparadas, SELECT

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli, prepared-statements

Estoy construyendo una galeria con imagenes con valores traidos de una base de datos. Al parecer si funciona, pero está bien?

> Ya fué resuelto , muchas gracias.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM productadm WHERE  cat = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $categorian);
$stmt->execute();
$resultado = $stmt->get_result();
  while($tprodadm = $resultado->fetch_array()){ 

**--- AQUI TODAS LAS IMAGENES CON SUS DATOS ---** 

}
```

> Pero:

Y por ejemplo, si antes tenia mi sentencia así:

```
SELECT * FROM productadm  WHERE name like '%$busqueda%' AND ...
```

como haría en una sentencia preparada??

Comment: Lectura recomendada [mysqli_prepare()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php). Inténtalo y con gusto te ayudamos si tienes algún error, solo necesitamos ver algo más concreto.

Comment: Ok ya hiciste una edición ahora ¿cuál es el problema con ese código?

Comment: Esta preguntando si el codigo esta correcto, me imagino que intentas averiguar si esta bien escrito, para evitar inyecciones, mi pregunta es para que el $asd?

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta para explicar cómo agregar más campos en la consulta.

Answer (score 1):

No debes mezclar programación por procedimientos `mysqli_funcion_X()` y orientada a objetos `objeto->funcion_X()`.

Por supuesto, al conectar debiste usar `$mysqli = new mysqli(/* datos de conexión */);` como se especifica en el [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.construct.php)

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM productadm WHERE  cat = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $categorian);
$stmt->execute();
$resultado = $stmt->get_result();
while($tprodadm = $resultado->fetch_array()){  
    /**--- AQUÍ TODAS LAS IMÁGENES CON SUS DATOS ---**/
}
```

Muy bien de tu parte por investigar, probar y **editar la pregunta para demostrar lo que estás intentando**, *no debes poner ahí la solución*.

### Actualización:

Puedes agregar todos los marcadores `?` que necesites y enlazarlos con [bind_param()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), por ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE varEntero = ? AND varCadena1 = ? AND varCadenaX = ?
```

Se agregaron 3 marcadores, uno debe ser entero y los otros dos cadena, el primer parámetro de `bind_param()` describe el tipo de dato para cada valor: `iss` y después se deben agregar los parámetros correspondientes:

```
$stmt->bind_param(
    // Un identificador de tipo para cada marcador en el mismo orden que se agregaron en la consulta
    'iss',  // Un entero (i), una cadena (s), una cadena (s)
    // Un valor para cada marcador en el mismo orden que se agregaron en la consulta
    $varEntero,  // Un entero
    $varCadena1, // Una cadena
    $varCadenaX  // Una cadena
);
```